# Using ETag with Database data based on Trigger

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, triggers, etag

I have MySQL database with table named grades that has only {gradeId,gradeValue} and web service that retrieves grades from DB.

I want user to get data when it is only updated based on Database Trigger else get cached version of it instead of querying database again.

kindly advise how to do that.

I am using C#.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks

Comment: Without a date in that table, there is no practical way to know. You could use a trigger but where would you save the updated data?

Comment: @MadMyche thanks for your quick response ...this is a normal DB, the table contains data (about 100 rows only) and they updated regularly (hourly)... my only problem is that table queried a lot with no need to query the data again if it is not updated....so after searching i found i can use ETag on the webservice for caching... but i don't know how to query the data from db only when is is changed using trigger

Comment: @MadMyche sorry i misunderstand you ... i can modify the database to add date column or revision column to track changes

Comment: You could dd another DB column , "last-modified" date time , and send that out as a header and filter on that. Or you could use that value within an eTag as well. Just update the value any time you do an update

Comment: @MadMyche.. but this way i have to query data every time to get "last-modified" column.. i just want to query data when its updated only and return cached version if the request has the same etag.

Comment: How else would the server know if a document has been modified? The eTag or LastMod is sent as a header, and you need to check it.

Comment: @MadMyche Thanks.. Exactly .. this is my problem ... I want a way to cache the database records and return it from this service as long as ETag not changed and find a way to invalidate the cached records using DB Trigger when they're updated to return the updated ones from the webservice so users getting the cached data from webservice until it is changed on the DB.

Comment: Then your outputcache should be set to server only, and when you update the records you could clear the cache items